# GitHub Actions: Handling skipped but required checks

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I have tried what is in the GitHub actions documentation but have been unsuccessful.

My situation is exactly the same as the problem described in the　GitHub Documentation.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#handling-skipped-but-required-checks

There is a "Workflow A". This Workflow is required setting.
However, there is not necessarily a change in the files defined in WorkflowA. For example, if only the ".md" file is changed.

Therefore, we created "Workflow B" using the same method as in the document. We carefully matched the names as described in the "Notes" section of the document.

> Make sure that the name key and required job name in both the workflow
> files are the same.

The change file was pushed and CI was executed.

Workflow B is executed.(as expected)
Workflow A is not executed.(Not executed as expected. However, required should not be passed.)
Workflow A is a required item, so PR cannot merge it.

Am I doing something wrong? Please advise.

My concern is that Workflow A includes a task that sends data to a third party service(**Chromatic**). Does this affect the operation in any way?

**What I would like is for the Required Workflow A to pass with CI.
In other words, I want to be able to merge in PRs that have changed files other than those specified in the paths: of Workflow A.**

Workflow A

```
name: "WorkflowA"
on:
  pull_request:
  //omission
  paths:
    - .storybook/**
          
//omission
          
jobs:
  deployment-A:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
          
    //omission
```

---

Workflow B

```
name: "WorkflowA"
on:
  pull_request:
  //omission
  paths-ignore:
    - .storybook/**
          
//omission
          
jobs:
  deployment-A:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
          
    //omission
```

Comment: I just tried this and it works like a charm. Unless I don't understand what it is you are actually asking here.